# Is it possible to specify an image in a wxHtmlWindow that is contained within the executable?

Tags: image, wxwidgets, embed, wxhtmlwindow

I would like my executable to be self-contained. However, the wxHtmlWindow uses an image and it would be nice if the image could be stored inside the executable.

Can this be done, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `memory:` schema. See my code in http://mahogany.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=mahogany/M;a=blob_plain;f=src/gui/wxMDialogs.cpp;hb=HEAD for example (just search for "memory:" there).

Don't forget to register `wxMemoryFSHandler` or this won't work!

Comment: Excuse me, but can you tell me how to use a **dynamically created** image? For example, `wxBitmap bitmap(500,500); wxMemoryDC dc(bitmap);` and further drawing through `dc`. How to add such an image via `wxMemoryFSHandler::AddFile`?